# What is a reliable email client that will surely receive all mails sent to the forwarding address?

Tags: email, email-client, email-server

I have a forwarding email address (email alias) that can be linked with an email application.

However, emails sent to email forwarding address are often perceived as spam or phishing attacks by email application like Google Apps or Yahoo. Mainstream email apps might reject emails sent to forwarding address, resulting in me not receiving them.

What are some flexible email *application* that does *not* reject any emails to forwarding addresses?

The application should (ideally) run on Windows and support IMAP.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta posts on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/675/185) // [Are questions for service providers welcome at our site?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2713/185) // [Are mail service offering recommendations on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2733/185)

Comment: @lzzy Thank you for your suggestions. The question is now about Apps.

Comment: Well, the wording is about an app allright. But it's rather a question of choosing/configuring the forwarding service; the email app cannot do much about the problem you describe. Other than you describe, mail apps do by default **not** reject any mail (unless you explicitly configure them to) – it's the servers doing that (often based on SPF records etc). But even if, there are other details missing here, like what OS the app should run on, how much it may cost and, when it comes to specific mail providers, which it should support (while IMAP is universal, not all providers offer it).